# How to do simple pagination loop with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need your help to have an explanation on how to do pagination and loop on 5 different pages but with the same URL (http://www.chartsinfrance.net/charts/albums.php,p2) with just the last word of the URL who change for the number of the page.

I can **scrape** data of the first page but I don't understand how to get other URLs and **scrape** all the data in one loop and having like the 250 songs in one execution of the script!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 
req = requests.get('http://www.chartsinfrance.net/charts/albums.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
charts = soup.select('.c1_td1')
 
Auteurs=[]
Titre=[]
Rang=[]
Evolution=[]
 
for chart in charts:
    Rang = chart.select_one('.c1_td2').get_text()
    Auteurs = chart.select_one('.c1_td5 a').get_text()
    Evolution = chart.select_one('.c1_td3').get_text()
    Titre = chart.select_one('.c1_td5 .noir11').get_text()
    print('--------')
    print(Auteurs)
    print(Titre)
    print(Rang)
    print(Evolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code to `while ...` loop, where you load soup, get information about songs and then select link to next page.

If the link to next page exists, load new soup and continue the loop.
If not, break the loop.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.chartsinfrance.net/charts/albums.php'

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    charts = soup.select('.c1_td1')

    Auteurs=[]
    Titre=[]
    Rang=[]
    Evolution=[]

    for chart in charts:
        Rang = chart.select_one('.c1_td2').get_text()
        Auteurs = chart.select_one('.c1_td5 a').get_text()
        Evolution = chart.select_one('.c1_td3').get_text()
        Titre = chart.select_one('.c1_td5 .noir11').get_text()
        print('--------')
        print(Auteurs)
        print(Titre)
        print(Rang)
        print(Evolution)

    next_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("→ Suite du classement")')
    if next_link:
        url = 'http://www.chartsinfrance.net' + next_link['href']
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
--------
Lady Gaga
Chromatica
1
Entrée
--------
Johnny Hallyday
Johnny 69
2
Entrée
--------

... 

--------
Bof
Pulp Fiction
248
-115
--------
Trois Cafés Gourmands
Un air de Live
249
-30
--------
Various Artists
Salut Les Copains 60 Ans
250
Entrée
```